# Array only retrieving first LatLng data from multiple locations and passes the same value to the infowindow's content

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The problem I am facing is trying to retrieve "LatLng" from the array "locations" to a variable "tere" (siteLatLng). The way it is now it only shows the value of the first LatLng value and it keeps adding it to every marker. What I need is that it passes the "LatLng" from the corresponding marker.

This is the code from markers:

```js
var markers = [];

function initMap() {
 
 var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService; 
 
var guanajuato = new google.maps.LatLng(21.0158803, -101.2540116);
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       center: guanajuato,
       zoom: 16
       });
 
      
  var locations = [
      ['ocho', 21.017137, -101.253186, 1],
      ['siete', 21.017119, -101.252922, 2],
      ['seis', 21.017154, -101.253055, 3],
      ['cinco', 21.017444, -101.253144, 4],

    ];
  
 var marker, i;
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.close(); });

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
 var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng (locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);

var tere = ['sipissss'+'<div id="ddircontainer">'+ '<div id="ddirdiv"><a id="drivingDirectionsLink" target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=My%20Location&' + 'daddr=' + 
   siteLatLng +'">'
      + '<img src="img/car_vehicle.png" width="25" height="25" />' + '</a></div>'+ '</div>'];
     
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position:siteLatLng,
        map: map, 
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    markers.push(marker);
 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + locations[i][1] + locations[i][2] + tere );
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
   }
    })(marker, i));} 
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't getting function closure on the `tere` variable, so that is always pointing to the last value it is set to.  Add it to the function closure for the `click` listener function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i, tere) {
  return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + locations[i][1] + locations[i][2] + tere);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
})(marker, i, tere));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkf0jyv4/4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var markers = [];

function initMap() {

  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

  var guanajuato = new google.maps.LatLng(21.0158803, -101.2540116);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: guanajuato,
    zoom: 16
  });


  var locations = [
    ['ocho', 21.017137, -101.253186, 1],
    ['siete', 21.017119, -101.252922, 2],
    ['seis', 21.017154, -101.253055, 3],
    ['cinco', 21.017444, -101.253144, 4],

  ];

  var marker, i;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);

    var tere = ['sipissss' + '<div id="ddircontainer">' + '<div id="ddirdiv"><a id="drivingDirectionsLink" target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=My%20Location&' + 'daddr=' +
      siteLatLng + '">' + '<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.seroundtable.com/google-maps-iphone-icon-1355404686.png" width="25" height="25" />' + '</a></div>' + '</div>'
    ];

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: siteLatLng,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i, tere) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + locations[i][1] + locations[i][2] + tere);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i, tere));
  }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make "marker" and "i" become local variable

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    ...
    var marker = new google.maps.Markers({
    ...
}
```